# Won't let me add a Foreign Key into a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am tidying up a database and trying to sort all the dependencies out and I keep running into an error when it comes to adding a Foreign Key into a table. I have checked for constraints and can't seem to discover any so I am just wondering where the issue lies.

> 'PATIENTS' table saved successfully 'Appointments' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_Appointments_PATIENTS'.   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Appointments_PATIENTS". The conflict occurred in database
>   "OEPD_PRO", table "dbo.PATIENTS", column 'PatientNumber'.

This is the error which keeps flagging up when I try to save the table. 
'PatientNumber' is the Primary Key in the 'PATIENTS' table and I'm trying to add it as a foreign key into the 'Appointments' table.

```
ALTER TABLE Appointments
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PatientAppointments
FOREIGN KEY (PatientNumber) REFERENCES PATIENTS(PatientNumber);
```

I'm very grateful for any help/advice given.

Thanks,
KB

Comment: Show us the SQL you are using.  When your SQL has an error it is much easier to tell you what it is when we can see the SQL which is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to add a named KEY "FK_Appointments_Patience" when one already exists with that name.

Comment: This is the error messages thats flagging ''The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PatientAppointments". The conflict occurred in database "OEPD_PRO", table "dbo.PATIENTS", column 'PatientNumber'. ''

Comment: Look at the existing FKs on the table... are you trying to add a duplicate?

Comment: @pmbAustin Theres only one key on the table and thats the Primary Key according to SQL, even after a refresh

Comment: Are you sure you right-clicked and hit "refresh" to validate? Then the only other option is what is described below in the answers... that there is data that already exists which doesn't satisfy the FK constraint, so the FK constraint cannot be applied. You'll have to fix the data first.

Answer (score 3):

Check `Appointments` for invalid `PatientNumber`s

```
select *
from Appointments a 
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Patients p
  where a.PatientNumber = p.PatientNumber
  )
```

If they need to be removed you can delete them like so:

```
delete a
from Appointments a 
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Patients p
  where a.PatientNumber = p.PatientNumber
  )
```

Then try adding your foreign key.

Comment: You may want to create an 'Unknown' patient temporarily and assign these appointments to the 'Unknown' patient so they can be researched before deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because there are already data in the table that does not match the Foreign Kye values. Suppose I have the values 1,2 and 3 in the Patients.PatientId and the field Appointments.PatientId has a value 4 so that does not meet the constraint rule. So Before adding the constraint make sure that you does not have any such invalid data in the table.